# Fill between two line

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot generation:

```
gnuplot -p -e "set title \"Enveloppe\";
plot 'WATER' using 1:2 title 'MAX' with lines,
'WATER' using 1:3 title 'MIN' with lines,
'WATER' using 1:4 title 'MEAN' with lines"
```

[image: actual plot]

I would like to fill between MAX and MIN without hide MEAN, like this:

[image]

How do to that with gnuplot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one plot `with filledcurves` before all others:

```
gnuplot -p -e "set title 'Enveloppe'; set style fill solid noborder;
    plot 'WATER' using 1:2:3 notitle with filledcurves,
        '' using 1:2 title 'MAX' with lines,
        '' using 1:3 title 'MIN' with lines,
        '' using 1:4 title 'MEAN' with lines"
```